# AngularJS:12330 TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined

Tags: .net, angularjs, node.js

I am stuck in this issue and after reading a lot of answers, blogs and articles I wasn't able to figure it out, what's wrong with my code.

This is a modal for inserting functionalities

Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('nameSearch')
        .controller('ModalPPNameSearchController', ModalPPNameSearchController);

    ModalPPNameSearchController.$inject = ['$modalInstance','mdOptions','$window','nameSearchService','pendingPrior','nsCommonService'];   

    function ModalPPNameSearchController($modalInstance, mdOptions,$window,nameSearchService,pendingPrior,nsCommonService) {  
        var vm = this;         

        debugger;
        vm.pendingPriorReason = [];
        vm.pendingPriorReasons = [];
        loadPendingPriorReasons();

        if (!angular.isDefined(pendingPrior)) {
            pendingPrior = pendingPriorEmpty;
        }
        vm.pendingPrior = pendingPrior;
        vm.title = "Add New";       

        if (mdOptions.action == 'edit') {
            vm.title = "Edit: " + vm.pendingPrior.code;
        }

        function pendingPriorEmpty (){
            return {
            leadId: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            state: ''
           };
        } 
       function loadPendingPriorReasons() {                      
               var tmp = nsCommonService.get();  
               console.log(tmp);           
               tmp.$promise.then(getGetPendingPriorReasonsCompleted, angularErrorHandler); 
        }

       function getGetPendingPriorReasonsCompleted(pendingPriorReason) {
            console.log(pendingPriorReason);
            vm.pendingPriorReasons = pendingPriorReason;
        }
         vm.save = function () {
            debugger;            
        }
        vm.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
    }
})();

Service:
The service is getting the data from the web api.
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('nameSearch')
        .factory('nsCommonService', nsCommonService);

    nsCommonService.$inject = ['$resource'];
    function nsCommonService($resource) {

        var commonResourcePendingPrior = $resource('/api/ppreasons/:reasonId');

        var service = {
            get: get,
            getPendingPriorStatus: GetPendingPriorStatus
        };
       return service;
///////////////////////////////////////////
       function get() {   
             commonResourcePendingPrior.query();                     
        }

       function GetPendingPriorStatus() {
           return '123';
        }
    }
}());
```

I would some advices, because I think am doing something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: nsCommonService.get() presumably returns undefined.... why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from get()

```
function get() {   
  return commonResourcePendingPrior.query();                     
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But If you read in detail you will see 
That I call de promise in the controller, just added a tmp var in order to test the issue. And That exactly the problem. If you, please could show me what you mean?.

Comment: your tmp itself is a promise and hence you should be able access it as tmp.then()

Comment: I agreed with you, that should be, however I got 
angular.js:12330 TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined
    at loadPendingPriorReasons (namesearch-modalnamesearch-controller.js:43)
    at new ModalPPNameSearchController (namesearch-modalnamesearch-controller.js:16)
    at invoke (angular.js:4450)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4458)
    at angular.js:9014
    at hint.js:951
    at resolveSuccess (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:2730)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
    at angular.js:14583
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)

Comment: function loadPendingPriorReasons() {                      
               var tmp = nsCommonService.get();  
               console.log(tmp);           
               tmp.then(getGetPendingPriorReasonsCompleted, angularErrorHandler); 
        }

Comment: I rewrite properly that function as
 
function loadPendingPriorReasons() {  nsCommonService.get().$promise .then(getGetPendingPriorReasonsCompleted, angularErrorHandler); }
Result: The same issue

Comment: it should be function loadPendingPriorReasons() { nsCommonService.get() .then(getGetPendingPriorReasonsCompleted, angularErrorHandler); }

Comment: Thanks I tried with and I got 
angular.js:12330 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: have you changed your get as well?  function get() {   
            return  commonResourcePendingPrior.query();                     
        }

Comment: Yes, I did, Everything goes to the right path until I need to get the promise

Comment: my bad  loadPendingPriorReasons should be  nsCommonService.get().$promise .then and then update your get() to return

Comment: if your problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: For sure, sorry I was busy